# I cant able to connect the datasource in wso2 bam 2.3.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I am facing an error like test connection is not healthy.
I added postgres jar file in my bam lib. It is also showing me this error:

```
[2013-08-16 11:00:30,787] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceRepository} -  Error establishing data source connection: org.postgresql.Driver
org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.common.DataSourceException: Error establishing data source connection: org.postgresql.Driver
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correct data-source configuration in `<BAM_HOME>/repository/conf/datasources/ master-datasources.xml`. It should look similar to the following. And add your jar files in `<BAM_HOME>/repository/components/lib` folder.

```
<datasource> 
        <name>WSO2BAM_POSTGRESQL</name> 
        <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description> 
        <jndiConfig> 
            <name>jdbc/WSO2Bam_Postgresql</name> 
        </jndiConfig> 
        <definition type="RDBMS"> 
            <configuration> 
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/WSO2Bam_Postgresql</url> 
                <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit> 
                <username>postgres</username> 
                <password>postgres</password> 
                <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName> 
                <maxActive>50</maxActive> 
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait> 
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow> 
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery> 
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval> 
            </configuration> 
        </definition> 
    </datasource>
```

Comment: Check whether you have added Postgresql JDBC driver jar from http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html to `<BAM_HOME>/repository/components/lib` folder. I've tested with 'PostgreSQL 9.1 JDBC 4' version and it worked.

Comment: When do you get that error? Go to `Configure` tab in left pane and select `Data Sources`. Then check whether the data source you defined is listed there. Then click `view` and `Test Connection`. Then if it is working you should get a pop up saying 'Connection is healthy'

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the **Setup Configuration Files** section in [1] for configuring the Postgre as the RDBMS type.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Setting+up+with+PostgreSQL